# Retaining ElasticSearch query limit when working with Pagy gem

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, limit, pagy

Ahoy fellow developers!

I have a problem with limiting the total number of search results in my web application.

The web app is written in **Ruby**, the search functionality is powered by **ElasticSearch**, and the pagination is handled by the **Pagy** ruby gem (documentation is available [here](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/)).

In my ElasticSearch query, I use the `size` parameter to limit the number of results. The limit works fine when I execute the query in Kibana. However, once I pass it to the Pagy gem method (`pagy_elasticsearch_rails`, in particular), the `size` value is overwritten by the `items` one (which I pass to set the results **per page** limit). As a result, the total limit I set in the ElasticSearch (120 records) query is lost.

Here's how I pass the query to the `pagy_elasticsearch_rails` method:

```
es_query = { min_score: 0.5, query: <the actual query body>, size: 120 }
collection = MyModel.pagy_search(es_query)
@pagy, @response = pagy_elasticsearch_rails(collection, items: 24)
```

Do you know how can I keep the total limit I set by the `size` parameter, and make it work with the `items` one?

Thank you!